# Postfix rejecting mail from authenticated clients

Tags: postfix, smtp, authentication, sasl

I am trying to configure Postfix so that it would accept mail from *authenticated* clients outside `$mynetworks`.

When I try to send a test email from my iPhone, which is configured to use port 25, SSL and password authentication, the mail gets rejected by Postfix. I get the following in `/var/log/mail.info`:

> Oct 25 17:41:35 mailhost postfix/smtpd[6136]: warning: 212.183.x.x:
>   hostname host212-183-x-x.uk.access.vodafone.net verification
>   failed: Name or service not known
>
> Oct 25 17:41:35 mailhost
>   postfix/smtpd[6136]: connect from unknown[212.183.x.x]
>
> Oct 25
>   17:41:39 mailhost postfix/smtpd[6136]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
>   unknown[212.183.x.x]: 554 5.7.1 : Client
>   host rejected: Access denied; from=<aix@x.com>
>   to=<aix@x.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[10.25.x.x]>
>
> Oct 25
>   17:41:39 mailhost postfix/smtpd[6136]: disconnect from
>   unknown[212.183.x.x]

Here are all my `main.cf` settings that have to do with SASL/TLS:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

How do I establish that the session is indeed authenticated?

How do I go about troubleshooting this further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much experimentation it turned out I had to add `permit_sasl_authenticated` to `smtpd_client_restrictions` (not to be confused with `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`).

This has fixed it.

Comment: Your post said that it had permit_sasl_authenticated for smtpd_recipient_restrictions

Comment: @ChristopherEvans: It did. What wasn't configured correctly was `smtpd_CLIENT_restrictions` (caps used for emphasis).

Answer (score 0):

Test from a system with telnet/openssl http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_test I don't know if the iPhone supports starttls, so you may want to test against 465 and 587 for ssl support. I think also you have it setup to only accept authentication if ssl is used.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding "smtpd_sasl_auth_enable" line to my main.cf and then restart postfix.(there was no problem with webmail I just get the access denied error on Thunderbird)

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve with this:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,check_relay_domains
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,reject
```

Answer (score -4):

The parameters you are specifying on the line:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

Are the likely culprit.

More on how to configure postfix relaying and access control can be found in the [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html).

Looks like you'll want to start by adding *.vodafone.net domain to the list of allowed domains for relaying.

Comment: Definitively **not**! You will _not_ allow the Vodafone domain(s) to be allowed for relaying. Never ever. Always use SASL but don't trust servers based on names.